# FormGroup.patchValue() results in loss of validator in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-forms, formgroups

I have pay-adjustment component and it has a payadjustmentForm of type FormGroup. I want to make one of the form control i.e. Invoice No. to be required or not required based on the value of another form control called Adjustment Type. So what I did was I created a custom validators and also subscribed the valueChange event of the Adjustment type. now ideally its working fine which is the case when I am trying to add some new data using that form. Validation is working fine but when I am editing the data i.e. a method called displayEditForm is called which in turn calls this.payadjustmentForm.patchValue({}) the validator is not working. Below I am giving the code that I have written

**pay-adjustment.component.html**

```
<app-standardtable #dataTable [cols]="columns" [data]="data" [dataKey]="'id'" (refreshDataExt)="refreshData()"
 [showAddButton]="showAddButton" (addNewRecord)="addNewPayAdjustment()">
</app-standardtable>
..
..
<p-dialog class="insertPopup" header="{{dialogTitle}}" [(visible)]="showDialog" [modal]="true" [responsive]="true"
  [style]="{'min-width' : '600px', 'max-width': '700px',minHeight: 'auto'}" (onHide)="hidePayAdjustmentForm()" >
  <form [formGroup]="payAdjustmentForm">
    <div class="p-grid">
..
..
<div class="p-col label"><label>Invoice No<span *ngIf="isInvoiceNumberRequired" class="required">*</span></label></div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
              <p-dropdown id="pay-adjustment_dropdown_3" appendTo="body" name="invoiceNumber" optionLabel="invoiceNumber" dataKey="invoiceId"
                [options]="resourceInvoiceDataDdl" [filter]="true" [resetFilterOnHide]="true"
                [autoDisplayFirst]="false" errorsTooltip formControlName="invoiceNumber" [showClear]="true"
                [formControl]="payAdjustmentForm.controls['invoiceNumber']"
                (onChange)="onInvoiceDdlChange($event)" [disabled]='isInvoiceDdlDisabled'>
              </p-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
..
..

<div class="p-col-6">
            <div class="p-col label"><label>Adjustment Type<span class="required">*</span></label></div>
            <div class="p-col-12">
              <p-dropdown id="pay-adjustment_dropdown_5" appendTo="body" name="adjustmentType" optionLabel="name" dataKey="id" [options]="adjustmentTypesDdl"
                [filter]="true" [resetFilterOnHide]="true" [autoDisplayFirst]="false" required errorsTooltip
                formControlName="adjustmentType" [showClear]="true"
                [formControl]="payAdjustmentForm.controls['adjustmentType']">
              </p-dropdown>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**pay-adjustment.component.ts**

```
requiredAdjustmentTypes = ['Overpay','Void','Underpay','No Pay Was Entered'];
..
..
get isInvoiceNumberRequired() {
    var adjustmentType = this.payAdjustmentForm.get('adjustmentType').value;
    if(!gh.isUoN(adjustmentType)){
      return this.requiredAdjustmentTypes.includes(adjustmentType.name);
    }    
  }
..
..

ngOnInit() {
    this.initPayAdjustmentForm();
    this.subscription = this.payAdjustmentForm.get('adjustmentType').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.payAdjustmentForm.get('invoiceNumber').updateValueAndValidity();
    })
  }
..
..

initColumns() {
    this.columns = [
      { field: 'resourceName', header: 'Resource', callback: this.displayEditForm },
      { field: 'dateEarned', header: 'Date', dateOnly: true },
...];
}
..
..
initPayAdjustmentForm() {
    this.payAdjustmentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      earningId: new FormControl(0),
      earningTypeId: new FormControl(0),
      resource: new FormControl(),
      resourceName: new FormControl(),
      invoiceNumber: new FormControl('' , [this.adjustmentTypeValidator]),
      invoiceAmount: new FormControl(),
      jobNumber: new FormControl()
..});

displayEditForm(payEarningDto: PayEarningDto) {
    this.dialogTitle = 'Edit Pay Adjustment';
    this.showDialog = true;

    this.payRollService.getPayAdjustmentById(payEarningDto.id)
      .then((data) => {
        if (!gh.isUoN(data)) {
          const result = data.result;
          this.payAdjustmentForm.patchValue({
            earningId: result.id,
            earningTypeId: result.earningTypeId,
            resource: { id: result.resourceId, displayName: result.resourceName },
            resourceName: result.resourceName,
            invoiceNumber: { invoiceId: result.invoiceId, invoiceNumber: result.invoiceNumber, invoiceAmount: result.invoiceAmount },
            invoiceAmount: this.decimalPipe.transform(result.invoiceAmount, 2),
            jobNumber: { jobId: result.jobId },
            payDate: { id: result.payDateId, payDateAsString: new Date(result.payDate).toDateString() },
            adjustmentType: (result.adjustmentTypeId <= 0 ? null : { id: result.adjustmentTypeId, name: result.adjustmentTypeName }),
            amount: this.decimalPipe.transform(result.amount, 2),
            remark: result.remark,
            disabled: result.disabled
          });

          this.getDDlValues(result.payDateId, result.resourceId, result.jobId);
        }
      });
      this.payAdjustmentForm.get('invoiceNumber').updateValueAndValidity();
  }
..
..

//Custom Validator
  adjustmentTypeValidator = (formControl: AbstractControl) => {
    if (!formControl.parent) {
      return null;
    }
    if (this.isInvoiceNumberRequired) {
      return Validators.required(formControl);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

As you can see in the component.ts file I have created a array of required adjustment type i.e those adjustment types for which I want invoice number to be required and then a subscription followed by setting it up in ngOnInit(). In InitColumns() I have set a callback for the display form to be viewed. Then I have also set up a custom validator that validates by using the getter. In the display edit form you can I am patching values to the form and then I even used the UpdateValueAndValidity() to set the validation but it didnt worked.

So the problem is that in case of the add data form its working fine and required validation is being applied but as sson as I try to edit it and maybe because of patchValue() that is being called in the edit method the validation no longer works however the * sign on the form which comes from the custom getter is being set properly.

Can someone help me on this ? I am stuck from a long time, I appreciate your time.

Comment: Have you tried moving the `this.payAdjustmentForm.get('invoiceNumber').updateValueAndValidity();` line inside the `.then` block?

Comment: @MishaMashina I did try that actually the problem was different, actually in patch value I changed the structure of invoice number if you see carefully the object structure has changed which resulted in validation failing.

Comment: @GRD thanks for you time and help brother , I solved the issue finally as you can see the reason in above comment.

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari Great! Feel free to connect with me in future too!